# Idenitifying "similar lists" for CodeFights challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, optimization

Two lists are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the lists.  I solved the problem, but I need to make it run in 4 seconds (Python3) for all inputs.  Any ideas for making this more efficient?

```
def areSimilar (a,b):
    counter=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b)):
            if counter < 1 and a[i]!=b[i]:
                if a[i]==b[j]:
                    temp=b[j]
                    b[j]=b[i]
                    b[i]=temp
                    counter+=1
                else:
                    flag=False

    if a == b:
        flag=True
    else:
        flag = False

    return flag

a= [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279]
b= [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]
p=areSimilar(a,b)
```

I think the nested loops are my problem.

Comment: Is this in an ongoing competition

Comment: what do u mean??

Comment: You said you solved the problem so is this question in an ongoing competition like codechef, hackerrank, etc.

Comment: deleted -- bad idea

Comment: @Abrar You said you solved the problem so is this question in an ongoing competition like codechef, hackerrank, etc.

Comment: this doesn't look like Java. Please only tag `python` for python code only

Comment: its a problem from codefights...there is no time involved in terms of solving...i get the following error > 
Execution time limit exceeded on test 13: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input. Agile_Eagle & @user1443098

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your logic is painfully slow.  There is no reason to use nested loops: you've turned a **O(N)** problem into a **O(N^2)** program.

First, the lists can be similar only if they are the same length.  Once you've checked that, go through the paired lists *once*, noting positions where the elements do not match.  If you find a third mismatch, they aren't similar.  If you get to the end with one mismatch, they aren't similar.  If you find 0 mismatches, they're similar.

The only case with any further difficulty is if you found *exactly* two positions where the elements don't match.  Call them `i` and `j`.  At this point, simply check whether `a[i] == b[j] and a[j] == b[i]`.  Return the result of that comparison.

Note that **nowhere** during this process do you actually swap elements.  You don't need to *make* the lists identical, you merely have to identify whether it's *possible* with 0 or 1 swap.

Answer (score 3):

A simple iteration through the two lists to count the number of differences will do.

```
import operator
from itertools import zip_longest
def areSimilar(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return True
    diff = list(filter(lambda t: operator.ne(*t), zip_longest(a, b)))
    return len(diff) == 2 and diff[0] == diff[1][::-1]
a= [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279]
b= [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]
print(areSimilar(a, b))
print(areSimilar([0, 1], [0, 1]))
print(areSimilar([0, 1], [2, 3]))
```

This outputs:

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: That is brilliant

Comment: This Way 6/20 Test Cases pass ....Out of which 10 are Hidden Test cases and usually they are very large lists

Comment: @Abrar Can you update your question with the code of these test cases so that we know what we're dealing with?

Comment: they are hidden test cases as i mentioned and i have used up my coins to unlock the previous ones...i can give u the 10 visible one's

Comment: This doesn't work.  Simple failure case: `a=[0,1]; b=[0, 1]`.  Another simple failure is `a=[0,1]; b=[2, 3]`.

Comment: Much better; nice job.  This uses techniques more advanced than my private solution -- yours is more elegant (Pythonic); mine is closer to OP's tech level.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
def areSimilar(a,b):
    if len(a)<2 or len(b)<2:
        return 'Wrong input'
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    if len(a) == len(b) == 2:
        if (a[0] != b[0] and a[0] != b[1]) or (a[1] != b[0] or a[0] != b[1]):
            return False
        else: return True
    var = 0
    for i, j in zip(a,b):
            if i!=j:
                    var += 1
            if var > 2:
                    return False
    if var != 2:
        return False
    return True

>>> a= [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279]
>>> b= [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]
>>> areSimilar(a,b)
True
```

Comment: Execution error on test 1: Something went wrong when executing the solution - program stopped unexpectedly with an error.

Comment: @Abrar Don't use this code directly; this is just for illustration.

Comment: @Abrar  Try areSimilar() in place of check()

Comment: sorry i didnt see the check....It matched 7...Give me a minute to workout your logic

Comment: This doesn't work.  It fails on `a=[0,1]; b=[0, 0]`, among other cases.

Comment: This still fails on simple counter-examples.

Comment: @Prune Can you please provide me some tips for how to search all possible test cases? or how to make test cases? Thanks;

Comment: @Vicrobot: that's essentially a tutorial on testing.  Try searching for that; perhaps focus on the terms "equivalence classes" and "edge cases".

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on @Prune 's answer..It executes under 4 seconds but maybe u can write better

```
def areSimilar (a,b):
    counter=0
    ind1=[]
    ind2=[]
    if len(a) == len(b):
        for i in range(len(a)):
            if a[i] != b[i]:
                counter+=1
                ind1.append(a[i])
                ind2.append(b[i])
                if counter == 2:
                    if ind1[0] == ind2[1] and ind1[1] == ind2[0]:
                        flag= True
                    else:
                        flag = False
    else:
        flag= False

    if counter == 0:
        flag= True
    elif counter ==1 or counter > 2:
        flag=False
    return flag
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not very compact, but it works.

Since you are testing for the exact position to be the same value (with max 1 swap) you can use the same loop.

I have made the code below return immediately if certain conditions are not met, such as length of the array and if the array even contains the same elements (excluding position). The for loop then tests for the position and attempts 1 swap of 2 elements. The position of the swapped element has to be greater than the previously tested since we don't want to retest an element.

```
def areSimilar(a, b):

    flag = False
    swap = False
    if len(a) is not len(b):
        return False

    arrlen = len(a)
    if set(a) == set(b):
        pos1 = None
        pos2 = None
        for i in range(arrlen):
            if a[i] == b[i]:
                flag = True
            else:
                if pos1 is None:
                    if swap is False:
                       swap = True
                       pos1 = i
                       pos2 = b.index(a[i])
                       if pos2 > i:
                           flag = True
                    else:
                        return False
                else:
                    if b[pos1] == a[i]:
                        flag = True
                    else:
                        return False

    return flag


a = [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279]
b = [832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279]
print(areSimilar(a,b))
```